# Print multiple different labels with Zebra printer

Tags: c#, zebra-printers

I want to loop through a list of `Member` objects and print their names and addresses, like this:

```
foreach (Member member in members) {
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.AppendLine("N");
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("A50,50,0,2,1,1,N,\"{0}\"", member.name));
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("A50,50,0,2,1,1,N,\"{0}\"", member.address));
    sb.AppendLine("P1");

    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printerName, sb.ToString());
}
```

But surely there must be an easier way to pass multiple labels to the printer? Sending it once and letting the printer loop through a set of variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved this. Here's a bit more information to extend the answers from `OTisley` and `Brad Chrisite`.

I used this page to download fonts to the printer: [Converting and Downloading Fonts](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/eltron/epl_dl_fnts.htm).

And this code to loop through the members:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Member member in members) {
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.AppendLine("N");
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("A10,10,0,b,1,1,N,\"{0}\"", member.name));
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("A10,45,0,b,1,1,N,\"{0}\"", member.address));
    sb.AppendLine("P1,1");
}

string sendThisToPrinter = sb.ToString();
```

Explanation of the format sent to printer:
*A10* = offset left in dots
*10* = offset top in dots
*0* = Rotation of the text
*b* = The font name you set when you downloaded the fonts to the printer.
*1* = Expand the text horizontally x number of times.
*1* = Expand the text vertically x number of times.
*N* = **N** ormal or **R** eversed text.
*\"{0}\"* = The text to print.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I've always created the canvas myself. I basically created a "spooler" class that is a collection labels to print. A label is essentially a class which houses the basic format of the label (some are shipping addresses, some contain part numbers, etc.) in addition to properties I can populate to dump within the label's template. I then build a print document, populate the page settings, and bind to the `PrintPage` event and pop labels from the queue.

I bet if you got down to the driver level of the printer you'd have better luck sending a full payload versus serializing it, but I think the one-by-one will just have to work.

I'm kind of curious though, what is a scenario where sending them one-off is undesirable?

---

#### Further insight in to how I do it:

First, Create an interface specifying what a "label [class]" must expose:

```
interface IPrintLabel
{
  // Get or set the printer this label should print from
  // I typically bounce between a Zebra (UPS/FedEx) printer and an in-house
  // DYNO printer, depending the label I print for shipping.
  PrinterSettings PrinterSettings { get; set; }

  // Get or set the paper size, margins, etc. Allows me to setup the canvas
  PageSettings PageSettings { get; set; }

  // Method responsible for laying out the label (send it the event args
  // from the PrintPage method of PrintDocument)
  void GenerateLabel(ref PrintPageEventArgs printArgs);

}
```

I then have misc classes that implement that interface., with specific properties, formatting, layouts, etc. Then I have a "spooler":

```
class PrintSpooler : Queue<IPrintLabel>
{
  public void PrintLabels()
  {
    // Establish a PrintDocument and bind to the PrintPage method something like:
    printDoc.PrintPage += (s, e) =>
    {
      IPrintLabel nextLabel = base.Dequeue();
      nextLabel.GenerateLabel(ref e);
      e.hasMorePages = (base.Count > 0);
    };
  }
}
```

All generalized, but just to give you the effect. This is ~3yr old code, so there may be better/more optimized methods, but it gets the job done here (and got me to the deadline).

Comment: I just assumed that the printer would have some kind of memory and a loop function to loop through a list of labels. If you send them one by one and need to print 200 labels, then the system would have to wait for it to finish before releasing it. But if this is the only way I'll roll with it =)

Comment: One more thing. How do you format the text you send to the printer. I can only get 4 different font sizes. Not thinner fonts and stuff like that. Do you send an image or how do you style the text?

Comment: @Niklas: I use the label like an image canvas; I draw the features on it using the Drawing library, passing it font sizes, brushes, etc. to style the formatted text. I needed more freedom in regards to label style, so decided taking an image-based approach was more fitting for my scenario.

Comment: That's how I would like it too. But can you just create an image (bmp?) convert it to a byte array and send it to the printer? Or would you have to supply some of the information above? Like `"A50,50,0,2,1,1,N,\"{0}\""` and that stuff?

Comment: @Niklas: You would do something like the following, using the `e` (event args) variable from the `PrintPage` event: `e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("c:\\MyImage.bmp"), x, y);`

Answer (score 1):

What kind of Zebra printer is it? Can you use ZPL? You can't pass a set or map or array to a Zebra printer, but you can define variables in the format and later recall the label passing in only the variables. This would reduce the payload on actually printing the label.

In ZPL you would use the `^FN<Variable Number>` command to create a bunch of variable inside the label you are saving. That label would be large depending on how many variables you have in your set and how much formatting information the label has.

When you wanted to print that label, all you would have to do is use the `^XF command` to recall the label, and pass in only the variable data, so you don't need to pass in all the label information.

Stored Label

```
^XA
^DFR:SAMPLE.GRF^FS
^FO20,30^GB750,1100,4^FS
^FO20,30^GB750,200,4^FS
^FO20,30^GB750,400,4^FS
^FO20,30^GB750,700,4^FS
^FO20,226^GB325,204,4^FS
^FO30,40^ADN,36,20^FDShip to:^FS
^FO30,260^ADN,18,10^FDPart number #^FS
^FO360,260^ADN,18,10^FDDescription:^FS
^FO30,750^ADN,36,20^FDFrom:^FS
^FO150,125^ADN,36,20^FN1^FS (ship to)
^FO60,330^ADN,36,20^FN2^FS(part num)
^FO400,330^ADN,36,20^FN3^FS(description)
^FO70,480^BY4^B3N,,200^FN4^FS(barcode)
^FO150,800^ADN,36,20^FN5^FS (from)
^XZ
```

How you would recall the label

```
^XA
^XFR:SAMPLE.GRF
^FN1^FDAcme Printing^FS
^FN2^FD14042^FS
^FN3^FDScrew^FS
^FN4^FD12345678^FS
^FN5^FDMacks Fabricating^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: It's a `Zebra LP2844` and I don't know if I can use ZPL. But I guess so =/

Comment: I don't really have a label format because I only need to print two rows: `Name` and `Address`. But I don't know if it's easier to format the text in some way or to send each label as a picture (which would make the formatting easy). Right now the text look rather compact, I'd like it a bit thinner.

Comment: Sending the label as a bitmap is usually lower quality since it's not using the internal fonts. You should be able to try different fonts to get the text to look as you want it to

Comment: Can I supply the font each time I print or do I have to access the printer and upload fonts to it?

Comment: You should be able to just use the font if it's on the printer. they come preinstalled with several fonts. that's what the ^A commands do in ZPL